# How can you create CDs with media that cannot be copied?

Tags: security, media, copy-protection, multimedia

There are quite a few tutorials available on CDs/DVDs these days. When I try to copy the content on my hard disk, I just can't copy it. The CDs work correctly if I try to use AutoPlay option from the CD. What I need to understand is, how can one make CDs which can contain media, but it could not be replicated or played with any other player except the one that is available on the CD? Are there any such software available to create such media?

What other means are available for protecting media on a CD/DVD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No one has ever created a successful DRM system.  It is likely that this will never be possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as **DRM**.  It only makes it harder to copy the disc, not impossible.  It's very hard to do well.

The wikipedia article "[Digital Rights Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)" has a good introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do what you ask is to encrypt the media/data/etc when you burn it to disc. Have your program be able to decrypt this data on the fly (only within the program and in ram) and use it.

There are ways around it but this will probably be a very implementable method of moving forward.

Comment: This solution would not do anything to inhibit copying the disk

Comment: his question is not about being able to copy.. its not being able to PLAY the media... Copying an encrypted disk does NOTHING if you can't decrypt the contents... By enacting a type of encryption on the disk that only YOUR player can decrypt will in fact allow you to have this 'DRM' type of media. This can be done by having each 'player' having a priv key embedded and 'encrypting' this media using a public key. This way THIS media is only playable with THAT player.. Just as you asked. This differs from modern 'DRM' as modern drm is about compatibility... not this type of restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Though the CDs are copy protected, you can copy that CD.
What you have to do is just create one nrg image of that CD then you will be able to use that CD, althought the CD is not available with you using that nrg file